# ajax jquery selector not working in ie6-8

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-selectors, load

I tried posting the problem I had earlier, but I did not fully understand the problem and I had other issues that I confused to be part of this, so I deleted the post. Now that I solved the other problems and pinpointed the problem, here it is...

I'm trying to ajax load some elements from another page and it works in FF3.5+, Chrome 8+, Safari 3+, Opera 9.5+, and IE9.

I was trying to fix it on IE7 and found that it will only load the whole page and not just certain elements using selectors.

The code:

```
    navigation.children('a').click(function() {
        if(pageNum <= max) {
            $(this)
                .css({display: 'none'})
                .after(loading)
                .blur();

            $('<div />')
                .load(nextLink + ' .post', function() {
                    pageNum++;
                    nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]?/, '/page/'+ pageNum);

                    if(pageNum <= max) {
                        navigation.children('a').css({display: 'inline'});
                        loading.remove();
                    }
                    else {
                        navigation.html('');
                    }

                    navigation.before($(this).html());
                })
                .ajaxComplete(function() {
                    if (pageNum > max) {
                        navigation.remove();
                    }
                });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

If I change `.load(nextLink + ' .post', function()` to `.load(nextLink, function()`, it will work in IE7, but will display all the other stuff I didn't want.

Link to the problem: http://gavsiu.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are yousure nextLink is a string. Can you just cast it to a string and then try concatenating something like

```
String(nextString) + ".class"
```

Comment: it's dynamically generated by wordpress function and inserted into the page as javascript variable

Comment: why are u appending a space .post into the url?

Comment: nextlink is something like `http://abc.com`. without the space, won't it just be `http://abc.com.post`?

Comment: and u dnt see any js errors on the page.. the yellow icon in bottom left of the page

Comment: I have developer tools console open. No script errors. `http://abc.com .post` is supposed to be elements with class `post` on that page. The url is not the real link.

Comment: please take a look at .load api.. the 1st argument is an url I suppose

Comment: @gavsiu let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2589/discussion-between-zzzz-and-gavsiu)